App Crashes on Login with Firebase Auth and ProGuard Enabled in React Native
I am working on a project using React Native with the following libraries:
@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.0.0
@react-native-firebase/auth": "^19.0.0
I have configured ProGuard for the staging level. When I create an APK file and try to log in, the app crashes automatically. I believe the issue is related to ProGuard because the app works fine when ProGuard is disabled.
The logcat displays the following error during login:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken or an accessToken.
    at com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential.<init>(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source:2)

Here is my ProGuard configuration:
# Firebase Auth
-keep class com.google.firebase.auth.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.** { *; }

# Google SignIn 
-keep class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential { *; }

# Firebase 
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.firebase.auth.** <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }

# OAuth 
-keep class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.** { *; }

# Additional Firebase modules if needed
-keep class com.google.firebase.database.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.firestore.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.storage.** { *; }

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class org.json.** { *; }



